# Find the sum to n terms of the series $\frac{1}{1.2.3}+\frac{3}{2.3.4}+\frac{5}{3.4.5}+\frac{7}{4.5.6}+\cdots$..

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Question :

Find the sum to n terms of the series $\frac{1}{1.2.3}+\frac{3}{2.3.4}+\frac{5}{3.4.5}+\frac{7}{4.5.6}+\cdots$

What I have done :

nth term of numerator and denominator is $2r-1$ and $r(r+1)(r+2)$ respectively.

Therefore the nth term of given series is :

$\frac{2r-1}{r(r+1)(r+2)} =\frac{A}{r}+\frac{B}{r+1}+\frac{C}{r+2}$ .....(1)

By using partial fraction :

and solving for A,B and C we get A = 1/2, B = -1, C =1/2

Putting the values of A,B and C in (1) we get :

$\frac{1}{2r}-\frac{1}{r+1}+\frac{1}{2(r+2)}$

But by putting $r =1,2,3, \cdots$  I am not getting the answer. Please guide how to solve this problem . Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean $1\cdot2\cdot3$ instead of $1.2.3$?

Comment: @Matthias It is the same thing.

Comment: The values of A,B and C is not correct. Please redo the calculation. In my calculation A =  -1/2 ; B = 3 ; C = -5/2

Comment: Why is no answer accepted?

Answer (score 6):

The $r$th term is

$$\frac12 \left (\frac1{r}-\frac1{r+1} \right )-\frac12 \left (\frac1{r+1}-\frac1{r+2} \right )$$

so the sum telescopes.  The result is

$$\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{2 r-1}{r (r+1) (r+2)} = \frac12\left (1-\frac1{2} \right )-\frac12 \left (\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{n+2} \right ) = \frac14 - \frac1{2 (n+1) (n+2)}$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

If the $r$th term
$$T_r=\frac1{2r}-\frac1{r+1}+\frac1{2(r+2)}$$

$$2T_r=\frac1r-\frac2{r+1}+\frac1{(r+2)}=\left(\underbrace{\frac1r-\frac1{r+1}}\right)-\left(\underbrace{\frac1{r+1}-\frac1{r+2}}\right)$$

Recognize the two [Telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result to pop out if you play around with the indices of the infinite series and expand a couple terms. $$\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac{2r-1}{r(r+1)(r+2)} = \sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2r}-\frac{1}{r+1}+\frac{1}{2(r+2)} \\ = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{1}{r}-\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac{1}{r+1}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(r+2)} \\ = \frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{r=3}^\infty \frac{1}{r}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{r=3}^\infty\frac{1}{r}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{r=3}^\infty\frac{1}{r} \\ = \frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{r=3}^\infty \frac{1}{r}\left(\frac{1}{2}-1+\frac{1}{2} \right)$$ The answer should be clear from here.